# Calendar created is not visible in device's calendar application

Tags: android, android-calendar

I am new to android development

I am trying to create a calendar which should be accessible both from the application I create and My android device's calendar application.

Let me first give my device information:

Android version : 4.3
API level of application: 18
Device: Asus nexus 7

I am creating calendar using code given below

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(
    Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME,  "xyz@gmail.com");
    values.put(
          Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE,  CalendarContract.ACCOUNT_TYPE_LOCAL);
    values.put(
            Calendars.NAME,  "Test Calendar");

    values.put(
            Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME,  "abc calendar");
    values.put(
          Calendars.CALENDAR_COLOR,  Color.YELLOW );
    values.put(
          Calendars.CALENDAR_ACCESS_LEVEL,  Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_OWNER);
    values.put(
            Calendars.OWNER_ACCOUNT,"xyz@gmail.com");
    values.put(
            Calendars.CALENDAR_TIME_ZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
    values.put(Calendars.VISIBLE, 1);
    Uri.Builder builder = 
          CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon(); 
    builder.appendQueryParameter(
          Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME,"xyz@gmail.com");
    builder.appendQueryParameter(
          Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE,  CalendarContract.ACCOUNT_TYPE_LOCAL);
    builder.appendQueryParameter(
          CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER,  "true");
    Uri uri =this.cordova.getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(builder.build(), values);

    try {
        return calendarArray.put(new JSONObject().put("calendarURI", uri));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
```

when I run the code in application the calendar gets created but after that when I check my device, no new calendar created is visible there then.

I have tried like setting Calendars.VISIBLE property with value 1. and also searched for the solutions online but got nothing.

The code has been copied from the [link](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/androids-calendarcontract-provider/)

Please help me out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my fault, the calendar was added 9 times under the same name which was present from before the beginning of the moment I started creating application.